# Show dev mode and Yii toolbar on secondary site

Tags: yii, devmode

I am unclear on how to turn on dev mode as well as the Yii toolbar when viewing a secondary site in Craft.

Answer (score 1):

[devMode](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/global-variables.html#devmode) is a general config setting and it applies to the whole Craft installation (regardless of the site if you're running a multi-site Craft installation.

The Craft debug toolbar is a user account preference to enable and it should work across all sites in a multi-site installation as well.

Comment: I have the Craft debug toolbar turned on in my user preferences, but it does not show up on a secondary site. FYI, I am unable to log into that secondary site from the front end, it doesn't have such a feature.

Comment: Login to the CP should be possible also on your secondary site. You will only get a license warning, since the license belongs to your primary site. So if this really does not work, you should find out why this happens first.